# About a curious nested radical representation for $\cos 1^\circ$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, nested-radicals

I have found the following nested radical representation.

By using the triple angle formula for the cosine, $\cos 3\theta$, and making $\theta = 1^\circ$, we get the cubic equation $ 4x^3-3x = \cos 3^\circ $. In this step , I'll use a trick that is rarely used, by expressing $ x $ as

$ x = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3+\frac{\cos 3^\circ}{x}} $

Now I just iterate for x and in this way I get that

$ \cos 1^\circ= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3+\frac{\cos 3^\circ}{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3+\frac{\cos 3^\circ}{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3+\frac{\cos 3^\circ}{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3+...}}}}}}} $

Direct calculation shows that this periodic radical converges to $ \cos 1^\circ$

How to prove rigorously that the left hand side is the limit of the right hand side? That's to say, I need a proof that the nested radical converges to $ \cos 1^\circ $

Comment: Could you give a reference for $x = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3+\frac{\cos 3^\circ}{x}}$?

Comment: It comes from the cubic equation shown, which is equivalent to $  \ \cos 3x \ $ .

Answer (score 2):

You just have to show that $g:z\mapsto\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3+\frac{\cos 3^\circ}{z}}$ is a contraction in a neighbourhood of $z=1$ then apply [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem). We have:
$$ g'(z)=-\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi }{60}\right)}{4 z^2 \sqrt{3+\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi }{60}\right)}{z}}}$$
and $|g'(z)|$ is much smaller than $1$ (it is close to $\frac{1}{8}$) in a large neighbourhood of $z=1$. Done.